# Silverlight and RIA Services with LINQ-to-SQL DataContext - Unable to use client side linq queries

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, ria, wcf-ria-services

I have created a bare bones Silverlight application with RIA Services. The domain service class uses a LINQ-to-SQL class as its DataContext.

In my Silverlight application this works fine:

```
CMSContext db = new CMSContext();

gridTest.ItemsSource = db.Files; 
db.Load(db.GetFilesQuery());
```

But I'm not able to do this, for example:

```
db.Load(from f in db.GetFilesQuery() where f.Id > 2 select f);
```

Compiler errors:

```
Error   5   The type arguments for method 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.Load<TEntity>(System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntityQuery<TEntity>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.  C:\SilverLight\Silverlight 4 Projects\RIATest2\RIATest2\MainPage.xaml.cs    35  4   RIATest2
Error   4   Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntityQuery<RIATest2.Web.File>'.  'Where' not found.   C:\SilverLight\Silverlight 4 Projects\RIATest2\RIATest2\MainPage.xaml.cs    35  22  RIATest2
```

Any tips?

**Update:**

The solution is to add this:

```
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the linq query on a separate line:

```
var query = from f in db.GetFilesQuery() where f.Id > 2 select f;
db.Load(query);
```

Another option is to use a lambda expression:

```
db.Load(db.GetFilesQuery().Where(f => f.Id > 2));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I'm still getting the exact same compilation errors when using your code. I'm thinking I must be missing an assembly reference or something, but I'm still lost...